# Android Emulator's launch options don't work in Eclipse plugin?

Tags: android

I need to change the emulator's default time zone. It worked in command line with -timezone option. But when I tried it in eclipse android's launch options. it didn't work. I set it in Window->preferences->android->launch->default emulator options. Am I setting it in a wrong place?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

go to

> Run > Debug Configurations/Run Configurations

Tab

> Target > Additional Emulator Command Line Options

Comment: where is this additional emulator command line options? I couldn't find it. thanks.

Comment: Use the scrollbar on the right to scroll down to the additional command line options at the bottom. You wouldn't know it's there unless you were looking for it.

Comment: ah, found the option, Thank you both. Apparently the scroll bar is missing, so I had to manually make the dialog window bigger.

Answer (score 2):

I've confirmed that in Eclipse 3.5.2 that the Window/Preferences/Android/Launch/Default Emulator Options method works.

For myself, being in L.A. I typed in the following for the emulator option...

-timezone "America/Los_Angeles"

I created a new Android project, ran it, and the timezone parameter was already included for me in the new Eclipse Run configuration.

Using this method, you only need to define the parameter once, and not for each individual Android run configuration, as the first answer states you should do.

So, yes, you are doing it in the right place.