# Why the Android Emulator doesn't get the timezone from the OS automatically?

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator

Just wondering if, while launching the Android emulator via Eclipse, am I supposed to add the "-timezone " parameters to each Eclipse "Run" task I create?

Is it a bug or a feature that the emulator doesn't get from the OS (Windows 7 in my case) what timezone I'm in?

As a side/alternate question, is there a way to configure in Eclipse 3.5.2, that whenever I create an "Android" Run task, that the "-timezone" parameter is automatically added for me?

Its a minor annoyance to manually add the timezone parameter myself each time, but its kind of rubbing me the wrong way, that something that I would think should be so simple to do (poll the OS for the timezone the emulator is running under) isn't being done, or to just be able to tell Eclipse one time my timezone argument string, instead of having to do it over and over again.

Thanks in advance for any info/advice/answers.

EDIT: Got the answer (thanks Gary!) for how to set the timezone parameter once and have it inherted by any newly created Eclipse run configuration, but I was still wondering if anyone knew why the emulator doesn't just grab it from the OS on startup, instead of just defaulting to GMT?

Comment: Good question but it's a duplicate, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993282/android-emulators-lauch-options-doesnt-work-in-eclipse-plugin/2993414#2993414.

Comment: Thank you. For what its worth, I did try searching via Google as well as in stackoverflow itself, didn't find that question/answer.  Glad you supplied the link.

Comment: @gary I wouldn't say it's an _exact_ duplicate.  That question asks how to set the timezone.  This question asks why it isn't set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug.  There's an open issue about it being tracked [here.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2389)