# timezone in android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

have tried to change the timezon in android-emulator but it doesn't work. I write the [-timezone](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) option in eclipse menu: Window - Preferences - Android - Launch - Default Emulator options:
`-timezone Europe/Stockholm`
I found the timezone info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php).
In stockholm we add one hour to the british time. If my computer clock is e.g. **22.19** I also want the time in the android emulator to be **22.19**. But it always show **21.19**. How shall I give the -timezone arg to the emulator from inside eclipse so it works. I use winXp and Eclipse 3.5. And I have always restarted the emulator after each change of timezone.

Comment: Can't you just set the timezone in the settings of the Android OS when you run the emulator? Do you need to set it via command line?

Comment: Menu - Settings - Date & Time - Select time zone is grey and can't be changed, Set time and Set date is also gray and can't be changed either. As I understand it the only way is to use the -timezone option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
emulator -timezone Europe/Stockholm
```

Should work (on Linux). No quotes needed.
Try this is an adb shell:

```
# date
Thu Dec  2 00:04:02 CET 2010
# date -u
Wed Dec  1 23:04:05 GMT 2010
```

Comment: Okay, I'm confused. Your question says that it doesn't work. Now it works? What did you change?

Comment: This time I started the emulator from a command window as you said: "emulator.exe -timezone Europe/Stockholm -avd em22" and it worked. But I still don't know how to give the -timezone option in eclipse.

Comment: Found how to do it in eclipse to: in the accepted answer to this questiton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993282/android-emulators-lauch-options-doesnt-work-in-eclipse-plugin/2993414#2993414 It is set in Menu Run-Run Configuration: Target: Aditional Emulator Options.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it works fine!
Firstly you have to shutdown you emulator.
Then in the menu clic "RUN" and then Run Configurations...

On the left, please select "Android Application" -> [name of your application]

On the right, clic the "target" tab, then scroll down and look for the "Additional Emulator Command Line Option"  textbox. In that box you can specify:
-timezone [desired timezone]

Example: 
-timezone Europe/Stockholm //
-timezone America/Argentina/Mendoza //
etc...

Comment: Hmm, this didn't seem to work for Australia/Sydney. Now I worry about their time zone database missing entries. :/

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2993414/980687

Run>Debug Configurations/Run Configurations

Tab Target> Additional Emulator Command Line Options

-timezone America/New_York