# Eclipse android ADT ignores emulator options?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have set the following options in Eclipse to pass to the emulator command in **Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Launch -> Default emulator options: "-cpu-delay 0 -no-boot-anim -cache /my/custom/path/to/androidcache/" (without the quotation marks).** They seem to be ignored?

I understand from [Android Emulator's launch options don't work in Eclipse plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993282/android-emulators-lauch-options-doesnt-work-in-eclipse-plugin) that I can also set custom emulator options in **Run -> Run Configurations**, but that carries with it a different set of inconveniences.

Any thoughts? I've considered replacing the "*emulator*" binary with a script that reflects to it with the desired options. Any harm in that (perhaps it would interfere with upgrades)?

I'm using *Eclipse 3.6 (Helios), ADT 10.0.1, SDK 10.*

**Update**: I see from that same link above that perhaps this setting exists only to pre-populate the Run Cofigurations as new projects are created, which seems poorly documented and only moderately useful, since emulators started from the AVD manager ignore it (unless I'm missing something) ?

**Update2**: I made a script to replace the emulator binary and reflect to it with the desired options. Works fine. I assume it will be overwritten on an update. This is what I did, after moving the emulator binary to emulator_real (linux environment):

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/emulator_real -cpu-delay 0 -no-boot-anim $@ >> /home/myusername/emulator_out.txt
```

I was unable to use an alternate directory for the cache (as shown above)... it caused errors saying the cache was in use, etc, which I think has something to do with android not seeming to work well across heterogeneous file systems.

Comment: hey lacinato, if you post your findings as an answer I would be happy to upvote it.