# Can't get local and utc Instant

Tags: java, timezone-offset

I need to get local time and utc time in seconds. I read some posts in StackOverflow and found some solution, which is correct as mentioned:

```
    Instant time = Instant.now();
    OffsetDateTime utc = time.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    int utcTime = (int) utc.toEpochSecond();
    int localTime = (int) time.getEpochSecond();
    System.out.println("utc " + utcTime + " local " + localTime);
```

But result is not what I expected. It is utc time. The output:

```
utc   1593762925
local 1593762925
```

After debugging I found that Instant.now() is already utc. I can't find how to get time in current time zone, i.e. my system zone.

I found some solution in API but got error:

```
OffsetDateTime utc = time.atOffset(ZoneOffset.of(ZoneOffset.systemDefault().getId()));
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid ID for ZoneOffset, invalid format: Europe/Astrakhan
> at java.base/java.time.ZoneOffset.of(ZoneOffset.java:241)

UPD: My question is How to get current time in seconds in local time zone and in UTC? I.e. the number of seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00 GMT+4 and 1970-01-01T00:00:00 GMT+0

UPD2: I have some device that needs response with utc time in seconds from 1970 and sender local time in seconds. Why? I don't know. It is black box for me.

Comment: Why did you expect `localTime` to be local? You are doing `getEpochSecond`, an instant in time, no matter the offset, will have the same offset to epoch. An instant describes a moment in time, no matter where in the world you are at. So the instant itself doesnt change if you add zones to it.

Comment: Use a `ZonedDateTime sysDefZdt = now.atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault());` and mind that an `Instant` is a moment in time independent from zones or offsets. Basically, it is just a counter of (milli-) seconds. You can take such a moment and represent it in a datetime format applying a zone and/or offset.

Comment: So you did not expect both of them to be `1593762925`? What did you expect? What does "local time in seconds" mean?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, times are different. I expect that local time is +4 hours from UTC, but I don't want to specify it explicitly, because my application will work in other devices. I want to calculate current time zone

Comment: @ValeriyK. So you are trying to find the number of seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00 GMT+4? Why would that be useful? "1970-01-01T00:00:00 GMT+4" is not the epoch. It's not a special instant at all.

Comment: I think what you say you want is `ZonedDateTime.now().withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochSecond()`. But I'm sure you don't really want that, i.e. this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It would be great if you can tell us more about why you want this "local time in seconds". What is it for?

Comment: What happens if in your response you send the (correct) numbers you already have, that is, the same number twice?

Comment: @OleV.V. I thought that problem was in time but it seems another problem. #deHaar gave the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to take the `Instant`, create a `ZonedDateTime` (`OffsetDateTime` may be suitable as well) by applying a `ZoneId.of("UTC")` and then take that `ZonedDateTime` and use it to shift the locale:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    
    ZonedDateTime utcZdt = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    ZonedDateTime localZdt = utcZdt.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    
    System.out.println(utcZdt.toEpochSecond() + " <== " + utcZdt);
    System.out.println(localZdt.toEpochSecond() + " <== " + localZdt);
}
```

**On my system**, this outputs

```
1593765852 <== 2020-07-03T08:44:12.070Z[UTC]
1593758652 <== 2020-07-03T08:44:12.070+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

Two hours difference are affecting the sixth digit of the epoch seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7289708/7804595):

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Instant instant = Instant.now();
    int offsetFromUtc = tz.getOffset(instant.getEpochSecond()) / 1000;
```

Or as wrote @deHaar:

```
    int offsetFromUtc = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault()).getOffset().getTotalSeconds();
```

It gives 14400 s that is correct for my timezone. I can add this to utc.

Comment: The solution you found seems correct and was good in 2011. Nowadays, since Java 8, a pure `java.time` solution should be preferred over a mixture of `java.time` and `java.util`.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Your expectations are wrong. Your results are correct.**

The results you are getting is the count of seconds since the Unix/Java epoch. This is also known as a *Unix timestamp*. The epoch is *one* point in time and is independent of time zone. It’s the same point in time in all time zones. Therefore the count of seconds is the same in all time zones too.

The epoch is 1970-01-01T00:00:00 GMT+0. In some time zones (yours?) this point in time would be given as 1970-01-01T**04**:00:00 GMT+4. Please note the time of day is 4 AM, not 00:00.

**In case someone else was wrong**

> UPD2: I have some device that needs response with utc time in seconds
> from 1970 and sender local time in seconds. Why? I don't know. It is
> black box for me.

It’s a possibility, of course, that the designers of that device misunderstood and probably inadvertently invented their own way of counting seconds. It doesn’t sound very likely, though, so I would at least double-check and triple-check this piece of information. If it turns out to be correct, I would do something like:

```
    LocalDateTime misunderstoodEpoch = LocalDate.EPOCH.atStartOfDay();
    
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Astrakhan");
    long secondsLong = ChronoUnit.SECONDS
            .between(misunderstoodEpoch.atZone(zone), ZonedDateTime.now(zone));
    int seconds = Math.toIntExact(secondsLong);
    
    System.out.println(seconds);
```

Output when running just now:

> 1593881344

Also if your device insists on using an `int` for your seconds, at least use `Math.toIntExact()` for the conversion. This will throw an exception in case of `int` overflow so that in January 2038 (just 17 years 6 months from now) you and your users will be made aware of the fact that your device is no longer working.